# What template or library can I use to create documentation sites with expanding / collapsing menus? Example provided

Tags: sharepoint, office365

We're using the online version (office 365). Here's an example:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-edit-a-wiki-dc64f9c2-d1a2-44b5-ac59-b9d535551a32?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: in sharepoint list view settings, set the grouping by title, you should have something close to that.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say a dropdown menu with links, like Products Templates and Support menu in the link you have shared?

If yes then you need to customize the top navigation using css and jquery.

Updated:                                                                              You can create global navigation. In that create headings and add link under headings. 
Steps: 
1. Activate SharePoint publishing feature in site 
2. In site settings page, click on Navigation link.
3. Now Scroll down to edit the global(top) navigation. Click on Global heading and under that add headings. Under each heading add respective links. This will create your menu with expand collapse functionality.
 4. Style them as per your requirement using css.

This settings will be applicable to entire site. No need for template or library.

For more complex requirement, I would suggest to use java script.

Comment: I meant that but also more important, if you scroll down, there are expandable / collapsible menus. That's what I meant.